# Disable mouse clicks on displaying busy/wait cursor in WPF

Tags: wpf, click, wait, mouse-cursor

I am currently displaying a busy/wait cursor using `Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait`. But when the wait cursor is on it is still able to recognize the mouse clicks happened during that time. Is there any way to disable the mouse clicks?

Answer (score 5):

```
this.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

but a more elegant solution would be (assuming you are using MVVM pattern) to reject the mouse click in the RelayCommand `CanExecute` method.